# Huion pen not working

Tags: pen, digital-pen

I just bought a huion 420 and no matter what I do the pen won't work. It won't move the mouse at all. I think maybe it's the battery and I'm trying to take it out but I can't. How do i take out the battery? And if any of you had a huion tablet that wasn't working, how'd you fix that problem?

Comment: Which model of pen is it? Most are battery free, or are rechargeable.

Comment: All I know is that it's from a huion 420 tablet and it's not rechargable. It has one battery